# How Can I add sections of categories in gantt highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

[image]

I am using gantt highcharts in my angular application.
In Gantt highcharts, I need to add sections of categories(general processes and Products) which are highlighted in red color.
tried many solutions but didn't get the solutions.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your data sets, you can insert points only with a name property.

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'Offices',
        data: [{
            name: 'Section 1'
        }, {
            name: 'New offices',
            id: 'new_offices',
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, ...]
    }, {
        name: 'Product',
        data: [{
            name: 'Section 2'
        }, {
            name: 'New product launch',
            id: 'new_product',
            owner: 'Peter'
        }, ...]
    }],
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3knLtr8g/